Seeking a Proof for Eigenvalue Bound in Theorem 8.3 from Nocedal & Wright (Broyden Class)
I am studying the Broyden class of quasi-Newton methods in Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright, and I've come across Theorem 8.3, which does not include a detailed proof in the book. The theorem states the following:
Suppose $f(x) = b^T x + \frac{1}{2} x^T A x$
is a strongly convex quadratic function, where  is symmetric and positive definite. Let $x_0$ be any starting point for the quasi-Newton iteration
$[x_{k+1} = x_k - B_k^{-1} \nabla f(x_k)]$
where $B_0$ is any symmetric positive definite starting matrix. Suppose $B_k$ is updated by the Broyden formula:
$B_{k+1} = B_k + \frac{(y_k - B_k s_k) s_k^T}{s_k^T y_k} + \phi_k \left( \frac{s_k s_k^T}{s_k^T y_k} - \frac{(y_k - B_k s_k)(y_k - B_k s_k)^T}{(y_k - B_k s_k)^T s_k} \right)$
with $_ ∈ [0,1]$
Define
$\lambda_{k}^{1} \leq \lambda_{k}^{2} \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_{k}^{n}$
to be the eigenvalues of the matrix
$M_k = A^{1/2} B_k^{-1} A^{1/2}$
Then for all k
$\min(\lambda_{k}^{i}, 1) \leq \lambda_{k+1}^{i} \leq \max(\lambda_{k}^{i}, 1), \quad i = 1, \dots, n.$
Moreover, this property does not hold if $_k$ is chosen outside the interval [0,1].
I understand that the theorem suggests a form of eigenvalue stability for the matrix $M_k$ , keeping the eigenvalues bounded around 1 as  progresses. I also see that the restriction $_ ∈ [0,1]$ is essential to maintain this stability, as it keeps $B_k$ within a certain range of positive definiteness. However, I am struggling to piece together a rigorous, step-by-step proof of this result.
Would anyone be able to provide a detailed proof or offer insights on how to derive the eigenvalue bounds in Theorem 8.3? Any references or hints about tools and techniques to use (like properties of positive definite matrices or specifics of Broyden’s method) would be very helpful.
Thank you for your time!

Can you use MathJax to write your formulae?

Please format your formulas.

@AnneBauval
Thank you for the suggestion! I've now formatted the formulas using MathJax.

@Dominique Thank you for the suggestion! I've now formatted the formulas using MathJax.
